# Trouble with testing ios app on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

My project manager added udid of my device to "iOS Provisioning Portal", I download "WWDR intermediate certificate" and "team provisioning certificate", after that I download "team provisioning profile" and install all that tree files. And in XCode (XCode 4) I see warning "XCode could not find a valid private-key/certificate pair for this profile in your keychain" and in Target ->Build settings->Code Signing Identity I see the same message. How can I fix it? Help me please, I'm newbie in iOS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Xcode could not find a valid private certificate/valid key-pair for this profile in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525436/xcode-could-not-find-a-valid-private-certificate-valid-key-pair-for-this-profile)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to use your advice