# xcode valid signing identity not found

Tags: xcode, distribution

I can't find the solution for this problem for 2 weeks!!! That is enormous.

When I try to validate my app I face an error. Xcode shows: Valid signing identity for ... not found. I don't know what do and I have tried a lot. Please help.

Here are the print-screens:

[Image1 http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/9749/20120910195154.png](http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/9749/20120910195154.png)
[Full Size](http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/9749/20120910195154.png)

[Image2 http://img100.imageshack.us/img100/9126/20120910195440.png](http://img100.imageshack.us/img100/9126/20120910195440.png)
[Full Size](http://img100.imageshack.us/img100/9126/20120910195440.png)

Comment: How did you solved your problem? I'm facing the same problem as you

Answer (score 1):

I think deleting all the certificates and re-making them should solve your problem

Check out the top answer in this thread for steps to do the same

[Xcode could not find a valid private-key certificate pair for this profile in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424017/xcode-could-not-find-a-valid-private-key-certificate-pair-for-this-profile-in-yo)

Comment: didn't work for me. I remade it from developer centre and reimported it. still the same error.