# xcode "valid signing identity not found" distribution profile

Tags: ios, xcode

i seem to be having a similar problem to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355387/xcode-valid-signing-identity-not-found) except the difference being that I am a developer on 2 teams.
My team generates adhoc distribution provisioning files fine (Team A) i am also the creater of this team. when i create one for team B i hit a problem where my xcode says "valid signing identity not found".

I have tried deleting, re importing distribution certs etcetc.weirdly i can create a Development provision just fine, but not a distribution one. Team B have created me as an admin in their system, but no luck. i am stumped.

We considered revoking his distribution cert and recreating it, will that work? note: he does have other apps in the app store already with this.

grrrrrr

note: i need it to be an adhoc ditribution so that i can hand it over to testFlight

I should also add that i have Team B's full distro cert (with the private key). he exported it for me. didnt help either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved it.
instead of downloading the ditro cert, or getting the dev who generated the cert to send you the cert with the private key, i just got him to open the organiser in his xcode, select his team (the one i am on) and export the profile (password needed), and send it to me to import.

all the keys and certs come accross correctly and the provision file is now valid