# No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting errors while creating IPA.
No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “were found.
and also error
: Invalid .ipa file: missing a Payload and a .app folder

I am not getting what this error says.

what to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open up Preferences from Xcode (Xcode -> Preferences), and then in the Accounts tab click on your AppleID. Click the view details tab, and then click on your projects provisioning profile, then click on the refresh on the bottom left corner.

In addition, this question has a well explained answer in steps here: 
[Xcode could not find a valid private-key certificate pair for this profile in your keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424017/xcode-could-not-find-a-valid-private-key-certificate-pair-for-this-profile-in-yo)