# How to resolve the error "No Code Signing identifies found" in Xcode?

Tags: ios

Here, I am facing an issue when i am generate Archive for ipa i got an error [![Here I post a image ]]

[image: Here I got warning of No code signinh identities found]

[image: And the Second Screen shot display when i am generating Archive for ipa. So please help me ...]

Comment: Looks like Your provision profile is not  valid. Download latest from developer protal

Comment: You have Apple developer account?

Comment: You might find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424017/xcode-could-not-find-a-valid-private-key-certificate-pair-for-this-profile-in-yo).

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate the .ipa file, you are required to create a valid signing certificate from Apple developers portal. After creating download the all necessary certificate and provisioning profile then add them to the Xcode tool. Follow the below links to understand more about your issue.

1. [Create a Certificate for Production](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/create-distribution-certificate)
2. [iOS Code Signing & Provisioning in a Nutshell](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-code-signing-provisioning-in-a-nutshell-d5b247760bef)