# Enterprise iOS provisioning profile renewal error: "Xcode could not determine the profile's team"

Tags: ios, enterprise, provisioning-profile

*This is my first post here, so I apologize in advance for any breaches of etiquette.*

I've been working in iOS for about a year, dealing exclusively in enterprise applications for my employer. Our primary provisioning profile is on the verge of expiration and I can't figure out why I'm getting this error message when I attempt to renew it through Xcode's Organizer.

> **Xcode could not determine the profile's team.**
>
> Xcode could not determine the team from which "Profile Name" was generated.

We've had no recent changes in project organization, no team additions or splitting, and I've renewed this profile in the past without incident. I do have two teams showing up in Organizer for some reason: the correct one, and one whose name is the 10-character alphanumeric bundle ID prefix of one of our apps. I can't figure out where the team names are coming from or how to get rid of the one causing the ambiguity.

I've been unable to find any record of this error message elsewhere, so I suspect it's a well-worn error in new packaging. I'd be grateful for any direction on solving this.

Comment: Have you seen [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525436/xcode-could-not-find-a-valid-private-certificate-valid-key-pair-for-this-profile)? I believe it answers what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that seems to be it.

Comment: Glad you got it working.