# cannot get app onto iphone to test

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Im trying to test my first iphone app on a device. ive been through the walkthrough in the apple development portal that takes you through creating certificates, installing them and creating provisioner profile for the phone and installing it onto the phone. all was going well until i got to the end when it told me to select my device (that is connected to the mac) from the drop down menu in the top left of xcode then build and run the app. My device wasnt listed, i had two simulators and one that just said IOS device, i tried building to the 'IOS device' one and it built successfully but nothing was showing on the phone. So i tried googling the problem where someone suggested restarting, after i restarted i tried building again but got this error:

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

now i generated the everything from the same mac so i dont understand how the key pair doesnt match up. Help!?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the samething. Have a look on iOS provisioning portal page under provisioning profiles. You might have an out of date profile? If not open xcode and go to the organizer window under the window menu and look at your profiles. It could even be that you havn't added the device to the provisioning profile. sorry if im not making sense there are just alot of things to check.

[iOS Provisioning Page](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action)

Comment: Hi Azza thanks for replying its driving me mad trying to work this out. in organiser i have my device listed on the left hand side under 'devices'. When i go onto provisioning profiles i can see the pp i created and when i select it my device is there next to 'devices'in the information box above... there are no others listed. what else should i check?

Comment: just been looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108503/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid-certific but i cant see 'target' in the groups and files list... is is different in xcode 4.1

Comment: when you click your device in organizer look for the "provisioning" part what does it say there? does it list your provisioning profile? maybe try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391786/xcode-iphone-profile-doesnt-match-any-valid-certificate-private-key-pair-in)

Comment: target is clicking the top hierarchy of you project. after you do that go to "build settings" then type in search "code signing" change the selected profile to your current one