# Create new certificates for a new Mac

Tags: xcode, certificate

I was developing apps with my Mac at work with my developer account.
I have now a new Mac (retina!) and I have to get a certificates again because I dont have the old one from the old mac (don't have him).

I followed the apple dev site guide, but when I tried to upload to the iPhone, I got the code signing error. I guess that's because I dont have the private key or something.
I remember that I have to upload something to the site then download again, but I can't find that guide anywhere.

I just CAN'T find simple steps on how to do that. CAN'T. All the links I found here led to Apple's awful guides which didn't help much.

Can someone guide me HERE, what are the exact steps to create everything from scratch on a new Mac, so I can program for the iPhone.

(And if you can, also answer this: I didn't understand Apple's diagram of private/public keys. The public is used to encrypt what? Who sends the public and when does the private open it? I don't get it.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get your private key out of your old Mac. If you can't do that, you'll have to generate a new private key, and start at the beginning with Apple.

Also, you can go to the Organizer in Xcode for your certificate / provisioning needs, it's much easier these days.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5392177/420001) regarding the private key generation.