# Error while running ios device from xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I am creating an app in IOS with Cordova (2.1.0) framework. When I build the app for the device selected in Xcode, it gives me following error:

```
**The identity 'iPhone Developer: balh-blah (XXXXXXXX)' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains.**
```

This is becoming a bottleneck. I have tried deleting derived data for the project, but it doesn't solve the issue. Also, the provisioning profile I select in build settings has not expired.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue is discussed under the following post: [Xcode - iPhone - profile doesn't match any valid certificate-/private-key pair in the default keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391786/xcode-iphone-profile-doesnt-match-any-valid-certificate-private-key-pair-i) 
Also i must point out that as of May 1st any application submitted to the app store with a cordova version less than 2.5.0 will be rejected(http://phonegap.com/blog/build/new-apple-app-store-submittal-rules/)